# How to iterate over a loop to make multiple client connections with socket server async

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, python-socketio

Here I have the async code in python-socketio from the docs   https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/

I'm able to establish the single connection between client and server and emit few messages. but i just want to create more number of clients connected to socket server and parallelly wants to observe the performance of the emit messages.

**client.py**

```
import random
import gevent
import time
import socketio
import asyncio

class ConnectionTest():
     def __init__(self):
        self.sio = socketio.AsyncClient(handle_sigint=True, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)


     async def listen_to_redis(self):
        await self.sio.connect('http://dfs.confec.co.in/?socket_qa2=True&session_id='+str(random.randint(1,100000))) 
        @self.sio.on('custom_event')
        async def on_custom_event(data):
            await self.sio.emit('message', '27 July 2015) was an Indian aerospace scientist')
        @self.sio.on('client')
        async def on_client(data):
            pass

     async def run(self):
        await self.listen_to_redis() 

     async def main():
        async def iterations(i):
            print("connection :",i)
            obj1 = ConnectionTest()
            await obj1.run()
            await obj1.sio.wait()
       x = [iterations(i) for i in range(2000)]
       await asyncio.gather(*x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Server.py**

```
import uvicorn
import asyncio
import socketio
import aiohttp


url='redis://my_master:q2_gadse@10.1.7.4:6379/0'
channel='public_chat'
mgr = socketio.AsyncRedisManager(url=url, channel=channel, write_only=False)
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp',client_manager=mgr, async_handlers=True, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

app = aiohttp.web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
async def test_connect(sid, environ):
      print('connected', sid)


@sio.event
async def message(sid, message):
      await sio.emit('client', message)



@sio.on('disconnect')
async def test_disconnect(sid):
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__=='__main__':
    aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=31451)
```

**Update:**

I'm able to get the performance for multiple asyncclient objects and i updated the code as well but I m not sure of why the cpu is 100% all the time with any of the deployment strategies. My target is to  get atleast 5000 connections with a single processor and earlier my target was 10,000.

Hardware which I have is 4GB ram with 2 cores and 4 cores. I'm running client and server in different linux nodes. I see the client is quickly hitting the 100-200%cpu and server is somehow managing as I was using redis as a middleware to emit from outside script.

I have gone through the python-socketio document but I have not seen the section for performance tuning/Load testing/Stress like socket.io in nodejs. Here's the stats that I would like to show and how can i achieve the connections with atleast 5000 per process. Is there any code changes i could make for it. I need valuable suggestion as I was struck with it.

[stress stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM7DP.png)

Comment: You need to use a different `AsyncClient` object for each client, each object represents a single client and cannot be used to connect multiple times.

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Thanks for the response. I have been going through your videos and official website for my work. Sadly I was struck. I'm able to achieve AsyncClient for multiple clients but cpu is highly overloaded.

Comment: I can't able to create minimum 5000 connections for 1 processor as cpu 100% for my client or server. I have tried many deployment strategies. Would love to get the suggestion. I have updated my question with proper code and extra description.